# Public wifi & range extender + additional access point

Tags: access-point

I have a problem setting up a RE in client mode.

If i use the "universal repeater" mode, the RE can successfully connect to the public wifi network and when I try to browse to some site, the first page I get is the public wifi's login page.

Now, I want to set up the RE as client, in order to connect to the public wifi in a single point; then I connect the network cable from the RE to the AP's LAN port and create my personal wifi network.

The problem is: how to get the login page? I tried the configuration described above but i cannot access the login (and so i cannot access to the internet).

Maybe is because I set 2 different subnet (RE is connected to the public wifi and has the same subnet to the wifi network 192.168.2.* - The ap is connected to the RE via network cable using LAN port and has an ip like 192.168.3.*)?

Or maybe is because i I have to connect the cable from the RE to the AP's WAN port?

Thank you in advance for any answers

Comment: What make / model of AP are you using?